# "einige Zeit in Anspruch nehmen" vs "einige Zeit brauchen"

Tags: usage

> Etwas wird einige Zeit **brauchen**.
>
> Etwas wird einige Zeit **in Anspruch nehmen**.

I've always wondered how these two phrasings compare to express the idea of "take {*~~~ time*}". Does the latter sound more formal? Any difference to take note of?

Answer (score 4):

*Brauchen* is a quite ordinary verb and would typically be avoided in writing (in favour of *benötigen*), but nevertheless frequently used in conversation.

In your context (a process and its duration is described) both variants are fine, but in the case where a person is involved, which has to devote some of his/her time, only *in Anspruch nehmen* works, as in:

> Vielen Dank, dass ich Ihre Zeit in Anspruch nehmen dufte.